# Schengen type D Visa restriction for staying out

Tags: schengen

I have a dependent Schengen type D Visa from Netherlands for 3yrs multi entry. Is there a restriction for staying out of Netherlands. I am from India and plan to visit my spouse like for 2 weeks every 4-5 months and then return back to India.

Comment: I'm confused. Why is this getting off-topic votes? OP seems to be asking a visa question about making 2-week trips every 4-5 months. Why is that off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

No, Schengen visas use *explicit* restrictions rather than *implicit* restrictions so whatever time limits you have would be directly listed on the visa itself or in the Schengen laws. Outside of what's stated on your cisa the only limit is the 90/180 rule, but this only applies to C visa holders or D visa holders traveling outside their country of residency.

If your D visa doesn't have any special limits listed, then you can hop in and out as much as you want to.

Comment: Schengen C visas come with significant implicit conditions, especially if they are valid for longer than six months.

Comment: @phoog such as? The only restriction is the 90/180 rule which is pretty explicit.

Comment: The 90/180 rule is not explicit in the least.  The "duration of stay" is given as 90 days, but for further information, the bearer of the visa must look elsewhere.  Another example: a D visa names the country that issued it in the "valid for" field, but it is (implicitly) valid for travel under the 90/180 rule to the rest of the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog it is explicit in the sense that there is a clearly defined rule, rather than the UK system of not giving a precise guideline on how long you can stay.

Comment: This answer says that by "explicit" you mean "directly  listed on the visa itself."  Then in the comment, you say that "explicit" means "definite."  Switching to a different sense of the word in the middle of a conversation is confusing.

Comment: @phoog answer fixed